# Write a function ticker() that takes as input a company name and returns the ticker symbol

Tags: python-3.x

I am having issues trying to figure out where to ask for the user to input a company name in my code, this is what i have so far:

```
def ticker(filename):

key = [] # company name
value = [] # ticker symbol

with open(filename) as f:
    lst = [line.rstrip() for line in f]

    for line in range(0, len(lst), 2):
        key.append(lst[line])

    for line in range(1, len(lst), 2):
        value.append(lst[line])

dictionary = dict(zip(key, value))
```

I am trying to ask the user to input the company name and when entered the code returns the ticker symbol for the company. The above code works i am just not sure where to ask the user for input and how to get the code to return the symbol.

Hopefully my question makes sense...Thank you for any help!

Comment: Have you tried calling [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#input)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this little bit of code, should resolve your issue:

```
user_input = raw_input("Please enter a company name: ")
if user_input in dictionary:
    print "Ticker symbol for ", user_input, " is: ", dictionary[user_input]
else:
    print user_input, " not a valid company name"
```

The user enter's a dictionary key (A company name in this case)

dictionary[user_input] gives us the value for that key.